# Можно ли как-то сократить этот словарь?

Tags: python

```py
dict = {2 : 2,
        3 : 3,
        4 : 4,
        5 : 5,
        6 : 6,
        7 : 7,
        8 : 8,
        9 : 9,
        10 : 10,
        'J' : 10,
        'Q' : 10,
        'K' : 10,
        'A' : 10}
```

Comment: Да, кончено. Просто убираете столько элементов, сколько не жалко. У меня получилось так сократить: `dict = {}`

Comment: для чего его сокращать?

Comment: Интересно, почему у валета, дамы, короля и туза ценность как у десятки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @insolor Blackjack, хотя туз не вписывается.

Comment: туз потом будет принимать значение 1 / 11 , как выберет пользователью.А по поводу сокращения , я думал можно как то диапозон от 1-10 написать не по отдельности

Comment: что-то по типу dict = {range(1,11) : range(1,11} , только правильно. Разве нельзя сократить эти 10 строчек в одну?

Comment: Это одна строчка. Тут нечего сокращать.

Comment: в зависимости от того, как словарь используется дальше, можно и вообще ключи от 2 до 10 убрать. Но тогда тут получится короче, а в другом месте длиннее.

Comment: текстовые ключи мешать с целыми плохой - плохой код

Answer (score 3):

Это не сокращение, но то что хочет ТС

```
{ v:v for v in range(2,11) } | { 'J' : 10, 'Q' : 10, 'K' : 10, 'A' : 10}
```

Comment: Код из ответа не работает. Вот такой код работает начиная с Python 3.9: `{v:v for v in range(1,11)} | {'J' : 10, 'Q' : 10, 'K' : 10, 'A' : 10}`

Comment: @insolor как всегда прав.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот так можно, только это не короче. Хотя от повторов избавляет:

```py
lr2_10 = list(range(2, 11))
dict_ = dict(zip(lr2_10 + list('JQKA'), lr2_10 + [10] * 4))
```

Или такой ещё вариант:

```py
dict_ = {i if i < 11 else 'JQKA'[i-11]: min(i, 10) for i in range(2, 15)}
```